# What is the difference between "other generations" and "the other generations"?

Tags: word-usage, articles

When I came across an article title containing "other generations", I became curious about the usage of "other + plural".

Can I use "the other generations" in the same sentence?  If not, why?

> [Here's how much more millennials plan to spend on the holidays compared to **other generations**](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/11/21/how-much-millennials-plan-to-spend-on-the-holidays.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can say "the other generations" if you mean all of the other generations (at least within the scope of the discussion). For example, in the context of Baby Boomers, Gen X, and Millenials, we could say:

> Of Baby Boomers, Gen X'ers, and Millenials, Baby Boomers are older than the other generations.

However, if you are only referring to *some* of the other generations, then you cannot use the definite article "the". For example:

> Baby Boomers benefited from post-war prosperity. Other generations were not so fortunate.

In this case, some other generations were not so fortunate, but not necessarily all other generations.

Answer (score 0):

I used to be confused with "the other" and "the others" too.

I think "the other generations" is not correct, because "the other" implies that you're talking about two subjects, while "the others" implies that you're discussing more than two subjects.

Obviously, there're more than one generation except the millennials, so you could say "compared to the others" or "compared to other generations", You can't mix them up.

Hope this could help.